# Clean and efficient way of iterating over ranges of indices in a single array

Tags: c++, for-loop, range, iteration

I have a contiguous array of particles in 3D space for a fluid simulation and I need to do a lot of neighbor searches on it. I've found that partitioning the search space into cubic cells and sorting the particles in-place by the cell they are in works well for my problem. That way for any given cell, its particles are in a contiguous span so you can iterate over them all easily if you know the begin and end indices. eg cell N might occupy [N_begin, N_end) of the array used to store the particles.

However, no matter how you divide the space, a particle might have neighbors not only in its own cell but also in every neighboring cell (imagine a particle that is almost touching the boundary between cells to understand why). Because of this, a neighbor search needs to return all particles in the same cell as well as all of its neighbors in 3D space, a total of up to 27 cells when not on the edge of the simulation space. There is no ordering of the cells into the array (which is by its nature 1D) that can get all 27 of those spans to be adjacent for any requested cell. To work around this, I keep track of where each cell begins and ends in the particle array and I have a function that determines which cells hold potential neighbors. To represent multiple ranges of indices, it has to return up to 27 pairs of indices signifying the `begin` and `end` of those ranges.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> get_neighbor_indices(const Vec3f &position);
```

The index is actually required at some point so it works better this way than a pair of iterators or some other abstraction. The problem is that it forces me to use a loop structure that is tied to the implementation. I would like something like the following, using some pseudocode and omissions to simplify.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_particles; ++i) {
    auto neighbor_indices = get_neighbor_indices(particle[i].position);
    for (int j : neighbor_indices) {
        // do stuff with particle[i] and particle[j]
    }
}
```

That would only work if `neighbor_indices` was a complete list of all indices, but that is a significant number of indices that are trivial to calculate on the fly and therefore a huge waste of memory. So the best I can get without compromising the performance of the code is the following.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_particles; ++i) {
    auto neighbor_indices = get_neighbor_indices(particle[i].position);
    for (const auto& indices_pair : neighbor_indices) {
        for (int j = indices_pair.first; j < indices_pair.second; ++j) {
            // do stuff with particle[i] and particle[j]
        }
    }
}
```

The loss of genericity is a setback for my project because I have to test and measure performance a lot and make adjustments when I come across a performance problem. Implementation-specific code significantly slows down this process.

I'm looking for something like an iterator, except it will return an index instead of a reference. It will allow me to use it as follows.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_particles; ++i) {
    auto neighbor_indices = get_neighbor_indices(particle[i].position);
    for (int j : neighbor_indices) {
        // do stuff with particle[i] and particle[j]
    }
}
```

The only issue with this iterator-like approach is that incrementing it is cumbersome. I have to manually keep track of the range I'm in, as well as continuously check when I'm at its end to switch to the next. It's a lot of code to get rid of just that one line that breaks the genericity of the iteration loop. So I'm looking for either a cleaner way to implement the "iterator" or just a better way to iterate over a number of ranges as if they were one.

Keep in mind that this is in a bottleneck computation loop so abstractions have to be zero or negligible cost.

Comment: I don't get why you don't program the code in the way you initially wanted, which should be feasible. Of course, you will probably have to pass the index of your current reference object into the function that gives you the indices of the neighbours, but that seems obvious to me... or is there anything magic going on that you're not telling?

Comment: Consider using an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) and use a compression to store it in a 1D array.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. The first code segment can only iterate over a single range. I can make it work with a custom iterator but it requires significantly more code which led me to ask here to see if there's a simpler idea or a more idiomatic approach that I've missed. Forgetting to use the current particle to get the neighbors was a typo.

Comment: @Ripi2 Unless I'm missing something, no matter how you partition the tree there will always be neighboring cells which are not adjacent in the 1D array, so this problem is not affected by that change.

Comment: Can you clarify why your function that's supposed to return indices instead returns pairs of integers? You then interpret those pairs as indices themselves, so it seems like you only need to flatten this nested index representation into a flat one?

Comment: Compressing means that each cell has an index. If you give indices by "adding a bit" (by level) then all children of a node are neighbours. Neighbours for a parent node are easy to find in the 1D array.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated the first two paragraphs to more precisely describe the problem. In short, I need to represent multiple ranges in the array and the particles are too many to list individually so I use a [begin, end) approach since each cell is a contiguous span after the sorting.

Comment: Okay. Since the particles all live in the same container, you effectively want to iterate over a set of ranges within that container. For that, I'd use an iterator specifically for that task. Check out the Boost.Iterator library, it has tools for writing iterators that do filtering, which is basically what you want. Important point is that you hide the complexity underneath in that iterator, which then also avoids dynamic allocation, which can have an significant overhead.